# Django with PythonAnywhere -- Operational Error no such table

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlite, pythonanywhere

I am trying to run my django project on PythonAnywhere and keep getting the error

```
    "OperationalError at /
    no such table: analysis_predictions"
```

when I go to my site.
I am using sqlite3 and python 2.7.  It seems like this is a common error and I have followed a bunch of instructions to try to fix it including adding the full file path to my database settings.  When I try to run python manage.py migrate in the pythonanywhere bash console I get the error "OperationalError unable to open database file".

Settings.py:

```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME':'/Users/Dahlia/learning_python/scifairserver/db.sqlite3',

       }
   }
```

Pythonanywhere console:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0j0H.png)

Current site:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oliIN.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from that screenshot, the path on Pythonanywhere is /home/dahlia/scifair, not /users/Dahlia/learning_python/scifair.

You shouldn't hard-code the path at all. Instead, use the BASE_DIR variable to calculate it:

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

Comment: That's what I had before-- it still showed the same error.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here.  Drop us a post in the forums, or an email to support@pythonanywhere.com, and we'll see if we can get to the bottom of it...